# play a set of sounds one by one using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, audio

I want to use AVAudioPlayer in my app. The logic is: firstly play a set of sounds at the same time and then play another set of sounds.But i found that the app only play all these sets together and cannot play one by one set.Being a newer,i found it is diffidult to me, anyone have ideas? Thank u for ur help and ideas.

Comment: Can you post a short, relevant part of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use Delegate method to recognized finishing of the first song then in that method start new song.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
   //play next song from List/Array of songs.
}
```

for playing song AVAudioPlayer code goes as below.

```
NSString* filename = [soundsList objectAtIndex:YOURINDEXNUMBER];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"mp3"];  

AVAudioPlayer * newAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
self.theAudio = newAudio; // automatically retain audio and dealloc old file if new file is loaded

[newAudio release]; // release the audio safely

theAudio.delegate = self; 
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
[theAudio play];
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for ur idea. I know ur idea is useful for play one sound by another.But I want to play a set of sounds simultaneously by another set， do u have any practical idea?

Comment: then you can create another instance with new sets to play song. But do u mean you want to play 2 sets simultaneously??

Comment: What? It is possible to create instance witha set of sounds rather than just single sound? Crazy! NO, i want to play several sets of sounds one by one, but as you know ,one set contains many single sound. Can u share the detailed idea about create one instance with a set of sounds with me? I'll appreciate it!

Comment: For example, there exist 18 sounds named by sound_i.mp3 and i is the number of a sound.Now i separate these sounds into 6 groups, that is, every 3 sounds to be in one group. Then, i play these 3 sounds in one group simultaneously and play these 6 groups one by one. Any good ideas can share?

Comment: I believe that would be a logic part. You can just put the logic in `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method and just increment the group number after 1st group of songs finished playing...

Comment: Yeah, this may be useful. Thank u very much